# Font not displaying in my WordPress site. I used @font-face to add it in the css directly

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, browser, fonts, font-face

I have the following issue with my uploaded font Celestina on the hosting.

I added a `@font-face` link in the css of my WordPress site. However, when loaded in the browser for some reason the font is not downloaded by Chrome, FF, Safari and can't be seen.

The direct link works ...

http://dnwedding.eu/Celestina.otf

Can you please help me?

Thanks

[image: Errors in Chrome]

Comment: You should at least share the code you are using or ask yourself why you load the page using the subdomain www, but the font without that subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I used this code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Celestina;
src: url("http://dnwedding.eu/Celestina.otf");  }
```